# Why can't I run node compile.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, solidity, smartcontracts

I wrote a compile.js file for a smart contract I am writing (for educational purposes), but when i run it using the `node compile.js` command I get an error that says `ReferenceError: compile is not defined`

I am using solidity ^0.4.17 in Sublime Text 3 (windows 10)

Here is what it looks like:

```
C:\Users\zakja\Desktop\inbox>node compile.js
C:\Users\zakja\Desktop\inbox\compile.js:1
compile.js
^

ReferenceError: compile is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zakja\Desktop\inbox\compile.js:1:1)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

Below is the compile.js file:

```
compile.js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');


console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));


Any help is appreciated. (Note: Newbie here)
```

Comment: It seems like the `solc` module is not imported correctly. Do you have it in your `package.json` and installed (should be)? Do you have a folder named `solc` (should NOT be)? ... Also you should pass the `options` object, not just the source code - see the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc).

Comment: solc is imported correctly i think. This is what I got after i imported it (npm install solc)

C:\Users\zakja\Desktop\inbox>npm install solc
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ solc@0.8.3
updated 1 package and audited 26 packages in 6.399s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Did you save the file before running?

Answer (score 0):

The first line is your file is name of the file 'compile.js'. if yes, then remove the first line. you don't need filename as content in the file. remove the first line and run.

Comment: Just did that, removed it from the other file as well but still didn't work.